Does IIS Express support byte-range requests?
I am using PDFTron on frontend and trying to implement an endpoint serving partial content 206 using dotnet and IIS express. After many attempts, in navigator dev tools, I finally got the message.
VM2080 webviewer-core.min.js:244
{
message: 'Byte ranges are not supported by the server.',
data: Uint8Array(1831)
}
So this means that IIS Express doesn't support this feature? Can we enable it through configuration?
